# Find and replace text in all files in Rstudio

Tags: r, replace, find, rstudio, find-replace

I am wondering why, still, there is not a feature in Rstudio to search all files in the current project (package) and replace a given text!? Or maybe there is one and I am not aware of!

`ctrl+shift+f` only finds in all files without replacement.

`ctrl+shift+j` (or `ctrl+f`) finds and replaces in the current file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is now possible with the 1.3 version of RStudio. You can learn more at https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/03/17/rstudio-1-3-the-little-things/.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a small RStudio Addin to replace in multiple files, which can be used until this functionality is included in some newer RStudio version. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The package is briefly described in my [blog post](https://skranz.github.io/r/2019/10/03/ReplaceInFiles.html).

Answer (score 4):

From what I have seen on [this feature request](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2066), it is already available ([this was the pull](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/5832)).

RStudio calls this [**Global Replace**](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/03/17/rstudio-1-3-the-little-things/):

> RStudio has long had a Find in Files feature, which makes it possible
> to easily locate text in your project. If you’re not familiar with
> this feature, try it out: press Ctrl+Shift+F (MacOS: Cmd+Shift+F), or
> choose Find in Files… from the Edit menu.
>
> In RStudio 1.3, it’s now possible to replace the text you found:

[image]

> After you’ve done a search, switch to Replace view via the toggle,
> enter your new text, and click Replace All. It works with regular
> expressions, too.

In order to test it, in RStudio in Windows, when one presses `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`F` it opens the following

[image]

And one can search in the following files

[image]

---

To keep in mind:

> You should be aware however that while we do hang out on the community
> site occasionally, the best place to make your request heard is on our
> Github issue tracker. ([Source](https://community.rstudio.com/t/ide-wish-list-collation/689/10))

Also, this is [how one write a good feature request](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/wiki/Writing-Good-Feature-Requests).

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find is [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200660503/comments/201039417), it is a pending issue sine 2014:

> Thanks for the feedback. We've got this as a feature request and I'll chalk up another request for this.

Comment: And a more recent one: https://community.rstudio.com/t/ide-wish-list-collation/689/5

Answer (score 1):

This is the Rstudio Github issue related to the enhancement:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2066

Feel free to vote up (thumbs up) the issue to bring more attention to it!